# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'. >

Tags: android, android-studio, android-proguard

[image]

I have 3 Android app in one project as shown above. I have a library called "mylibs" which used by all app. I want to generate a signed APK (with ProGuard) for app,app2 and app3. So I go to **Build** > **Generate Signed APK**.. then

> Errors while building APK

Messages shows as below :

[image]

**Gradle app :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.biocryptodisk.bookconverter"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0'
    testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',       {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(':mylibs')
}
```

**Gradle app2 :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.biocryptodisk.app2"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',   {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project (':mylibs')

}
```

**Gradle app3:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.biocryptodisk.uniqreader"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0'
    testInstrumentationRunner     'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
}
buildTypes {

    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile files('libs/epublib-core-latest.jar')
compile files('libs/slf4j-android-1.6.1-RC1.jar')
compile project(':mylibs')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
}
```

**Gradle mylibs :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

The AESCBC256Crypt and others classes stated above are all from mylibs. What I have done wrong here?

Comment: Please post your gradle script

Comment: I think that problem is in MainActivity as it can't find some definitions or imports there.